# Docusign Modify Existing Tabs Request - Unable to Modify Existing Radio Tab

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to set a Radio button to be selected initially when an envelope is created based on certain conditions outside of Docusign.

Testing using the following URL and request body.
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/163051/envelopes/49c4ebeb-331d-4cf9-bce7-843be646fbd5/recipients/1/tabs

Body:

```
{
"accountId":"163051",
"envelopeId":"49c4ebeb-331d-4cf9-bce7-843be646fbd5",
"radioGroupTabs":[
    {"documentId":"1","groupName":"RadioGroup","radios":[
        {"pageNumber":"2","selected":"True","tabId":"04ad92ed-377b-4389-8ec0-93999385c3f6"}
    ],
    "recipientId":"1"}
],
"recipientId":"1"}
```

Even though we only have 1 radio tab, we receive this response:

```
    {"errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
"message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Attempt to create 'text' tab from invalid tab type."}
```

Why are we getting this response?  We have checked and the RadioGroup, tabId, envelopeId, accountId are all valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, looks like you've identified an api bug with the platform.  In testing I've found that I can modify other tabs just fine (such as dateSigned for instance) but there seems to be a problem modifying existing radio button tabs.

I've logged a bug with DocuSign, not sure when it will be fixed though.  The August release just came out so hopefully by the September release.  Will post here once resolved.

Comment: Thanks Ergin, strangest thing is that this was actually working as recently as last week.

Comment: Hmm, might have been broken in the latest release in that case :(