# Error deleting tabs in envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having an issue when trying to [delete a tab](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/delete/) using the REST API which fails at the following URL:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/2/accounts/{accountID}/envelopes/{envelopeID}/recipients/1/tabs

DELETE with body `{"checkboxTabs":[{"tabId":"168229c3-d717-436f-b6a9-5f014d1817bb"}]}` gets:

```
{
  "checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "selected": "false",
      "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "tabId": "168229c3-d717-436f-b6a9-5f014d1817bb",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
        "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's unclear what the problem is and I cannot find a good example of the correct usage.  Is it possible that the tab wasn't found to delete?

**UPDATE**

I also tried an UPDATE instead of a DELETE and I got the following response body (interestingly the response shows textTabs instead of checkboxTabs):

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "requireAll": "false",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
      "disableAutoSize": "false",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "tabId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "INVALID_TAB_OPERATION",
        "message": "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation. Recipient not in state that allows correction."
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However this time the error message also contained "Recipient not in state that allows correction" which means I'm attempting an invalid operation as the recipient had already signed?  If someone can clarify that would help my understanding.

It would be very useful if the DELETE method also contained a similar message.

Answer (score 1):

That error should appear if the tabID does not exist. I'd recommend a double check the tabID by performing a GET against the same URL.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed tabID is correct by calling GET on same URL.  I found a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020052 which was related to a bug, but that was a few years ago.  An expanded error message would be very useful if it's unable to locate tabID.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll get that error if ANY of the tab properties you specify are incorrect.  For instance, you might be referring to the correct `tabId` but if the tab in question is on document 2 (for example) and you are referencing `documentId = 1` in your request you'll get that error.

I recommend that right before you send the `DELETE` request to first do a `GET` on the tab and then inspect all the properties returned and verify that they all match what you are sending out in your delete request.

---

**UPDATE**

I just realized what you're probably running into.  The [EnvelopeTabs: delete](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/delete/) API request you are trying to make says this for the description

*"Deletes one or more tabs associated with a recipient in a draft envelope."*

I believe this is only for DRAFT envelopes.  Once you have sent the envelope you need to do an envelope correction if you want to change aspects about it.  Your error message is also referencing this

*"Recipient not in state that allows correction"*

Comment: Thanks, that would make sense and I did a GET beforehand to verify.  However, I believe the underlying error was "Recipient not in state that allows correction".  Does that mean I'm attempting an invalid operation as the recipient had already signed?

Comment: Ah that's interesting I actually missed that part of the error on first read.  Ok in that case first let me ask is the envelope in `created` or `sent` state?  If `sent`, then has the routing order of the envelope made it to the recipient in question yet who's tab you are trying to delete?  If so then that might be your issue.

Comment: Actually my last response helped me realize this is probably due to you having already sent the envelope.  I've updated my answer.